# sfValidatorAnd fails when saving a i18n object

Tags: validation, forms, symfony1, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 1.2 with Doctrine. I have an object with the i18n behaviour. If I have the following validators, it fails when saving the form with error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null" (it tries to save the object_translation before saving the object)

```
$this->validatorSchema['phone'] = new sfValidatorAnd(array(
  new sfValidatorPhone(),
  new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 50)),
), array('required'=> false));
```

If I have only one validator (any of both), it works:

```
$this->validatorSchema['phone'] = new sfValidatorPhone();
```

The same happens with two other fields. So there is something odd about sfValidatorAnd and i18n. Do you know what can be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, but I still don't know why the original code didn't work. What I've done is having a unique custom made validator:

```
$this->validatorSchema['phone'] = new sfValidatorPhone(array('max_length' => 50, 'required' => false));
```

And sfValidatorPhone extends sfValidatorString:

```
<?php

class sfValidatorPhone extends sfValidatorString
{
  protected function configure($options = array(), $messages = array())
  {
    $this->addOption('required');

    $this->addMessage('required', 'The phone is required.');

    $this->addMessage('international', sfContext::getInstance()->getI18n()->__('The phone must have the international country code (+/00)'));

    parent::configure($options, $messages);
  }

  protected function doClean($value)
  {
    $phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9|+]/','',$value);

    $phone = parent::doClean($phone);

    ...code...

    return $phone;

  }
}
```